# Use Knockout 'submit' binding with child view model and inherited callback method

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm trying to solve the following problem using Knockout JS

- Need to bind a HTML form via "submit" binding to a child view model
- The call back method bound to "submit" is an inherited method

The following code will explain the above scenario better. The same can be found in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/omegasilva/j6Brv/1/).

```
function MasterViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.employeeViewModel = new EmployeeViewModel();
};

function EmployeeViewModel () {
    var self = this;
    self.empFirstName = ko.observable();
    self.empLastName = ko.observable();
    self.employeeList = ko.observableArray([]);
};

EmployeeViewModel.prototype.addEmployee = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.employeeList.push(new Employee(self.empFirstName(), self.empLastName()));
}

function Employee(firstNameParam, lastNameParam) {
    var self = this;
    self.firstName = ko.observable(firstNameParam);
    self.lastName = ko.observable(lastNameParam);
}

ko.applyBindings(new MasterViewModel());
```

In HTML, I use the submit binding as shown below;

```
<form data-bind="submit: employeeViewModel.addEmployee">
</form>
```

I've observed that always, the "this" context passed for the callback method is an instance of "MasterViewModel". I searched for a method of passing a different context with the "submit" binding, but in vain.

Is this a limitation that I'm trying to exploit, of is there a workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: Found the answer. Figured out that as the parameter for the "submit" binding (or any binding for that matter) you can pass JavaScript. Thus, modifying the binding to;

`<form data-bind="submit: function() {employeeViewModel.addEmployee.call(employeeViewModel, null)}">
</form>`

lets you invoke the "call" method

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
       var viewModel = {       
           numberOfClicks : ko.observable(0),       
           incrementClickCounter : function() {  
                 var previousCount = this.numberOfClicks(); 
                 this.numberOfClicks(previousCount + 1);    
            }  
       }; 
   </script>
```

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html
According to the knockout documentation if you dont already you should define the increment Click Counter function in your script and this is where you can take control of the value of "this"

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

'call' and 'apply' can modify the context. But any idea on how you could do this with in the knockout 'submit' binding?

Comment: @OmegaSilva I hope that helps. It appears to be wat you are looking for

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for. I was mainly looking for how to syntax the "submit" binding such that you could pass a different context. Found the answer see my comment above. Appreciate your help nevertheless.

Comment: @OmegaSilva good, i guess i posted the generic example, but if you want to take that function out of your html to neaten things up you could define your function where I have one. with a single parameter of the form element and then refer to it in your form where i have "incrementClickcounter". but if it works then eh